# Mongoose is not saving the data into the Database

Tags: mongoose

The data I have set is not getting saved to the DB. 
nickname, amount and mode are all correct;

I already tried to move the user.save() into each of the if statements - not working

```
router.post('/donations', function (req, res, next) {
    let nickname = req.body.nickname;
    let amount = req.body.amount;
    let mode = req.body.mode;

    if (!nickname || !amount || !mode) {
        req.flash('error', 'Please fill in all fields!');
        return res.redirect('/donations');
    }
    DB.findOne({ign: nickname}, function (err, user) {
        if (err || !user) {
            req.flash('error', 'No user in DB!');
            return res.redirect('/donations');
        }
        if (mode === 1){
            user.money = user.money + amount
        }else if (mode === 2){
            user.money = user.money - amount
        } else if (mode === 3){
            user.money = amount
        }
        user.save(function (err) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
        });
        console.log(user.money)

    });
    req.flash('success', `Successfully changed ${nickname}'s donations. New donation count: ${amount}`);
    res.redirect('/donations')

});
```

It should read the values from the request and update the money value of the user.

Comment: replace `DB` with `User` mongoose schema object.

Comment: The DB is my model